# Add Values in model in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am very new to MVC 3 Razor in ASp.net.
i am sending a model to a view that is tightly coupled to this model.
 this model has list and i want to display a SUM of particular field in that model list.
is that possible and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't do it in the View.

I'd do it in the ViewModel:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
   public ICollection<int> SomeValues { get; set; }
   public int MySum { get { return SomeValues.Sum(x => x.SomeValue); } }
}
```

Then the view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MySum)
```

Alternatively you could use a generic HTML helper, made generic so you can re-use across any model which has an `IEnumerable<T>` that can be aggregated.

Always try and keep your View clear of unnecessary logic.

Comment: is there a way to put a criteria on 
public int MySum { get { return SomeValues.Sum(x => x.SomeValue); } }
like where condtion x.value1=1 etc

Comment: `SomeValues.Where(x => x.SomeValue == 1).Sum(x => x.SomeValue)`

Comment: @Natasha - `Sum` and `Where` are basic LINQ operations on the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. So make sure your collection of values is of a type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, and you have imported `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it, but without seeing some of your code it's hard to be exact:

```
@Model.YourList.Sum(p => p.PropertyNameYouWantToSum)
```

Comment: i have a model like following
Card{ id, amount}  Card is the model that the view gets, i wanted to sum the amount. i tried your syntax but the Sum is not listed in the intellisense

Comment: `Sum(...)` will only on `IEnumerable<Card>`. Maybe you could post some of your code so far?

Comment: Decimal D = listItem.Where(P=>P.Amount>100).Sum(P=>P.Amount);

Comment: and how is `listItem` defined?

Answer (score 0):

```
Decimal D = listItem.Where(P=>P.Amount>100).Sum(P=>P.Amount);
```